# Recover all the videos ID related to an initial video

Tags: python, json, video, graph, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to construct a graph of youtube video ID for considering that the number of suggestion recovered at each step (let's call it **numberOfRelated**) and the maximum depth (**maxDepth**)  of the graph are fixed. (see attachment for a graphic explanation)

http://postimg.org/image/ytp80f02n/

I'm using the YouTube-data-api (v3), and I'm having a hard time with the time of execution ( if **numberOfRelated** = 10 and **maxDepth**=3, the time of execution is around 2min)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lib import function  as f 
import urllib
import  json 
import sys
import argparse
import logging

api_key = 'API_KEY'

videosId = []
maxDepth=2
numberOfRelated = 5

# FIND RELATED VIDEOS FROM A SPECIFIC ONE 
def getVideoRelated (depth, VideoID):

    related_video_api ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?relatedToVideoId="+str(VideoID)+"&type=video&maxResults="+str(numberOfRelated)+"&key="+str(api_key)+"&part=id"

    try:
        inp = urllib.urlopen(related_video_api)

        respRelated=json.load(inp)
        inp.close()

        # list of related video from a specific one 
        for x in xrange(0,len(respRelated['items'])):
            videosId.append([depth,respRelated['items'][x]['id']['videoId']])

    except Exception, err:
        print "error when trying to get the ID of related videos"

def getAllID(ID, depth):

    if (depth==maxDepth):
        return

    depth+=1
    getVideoRelated(depth,ID)

    BORNINF,BORNSUP = maxDepth*(depth-1), maxDepth*depth 

    for x in xrange(BORNINF,BORNSUP):
        getAllID(videosId[x][1],depth)



def main():
    url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HIuN5lxMCI'
    initialID = f.get_id(url)

    videosId.append([0,initialID])
    getAllID(initialID,0)

    print videosId
    print len(videosId)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Would you know how to do that more efficiently?
(eg : recover data with **numberOfRelated** = 50 and **maxDepth**=5 before dying in front of my computer)

It also seems that my code doesn't recover all the ID I want. I think it comes from this part of the code by I can't figure out the issue

```
    BORNINF,BORNSUP = maxDepth*(depth-1), maxDepth*depth 

    for x in xrange(BORNINF,BORNSUP):
        getAllID(videosId[x][1],depth)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've found this https://github.com/np1/pafy, but it doesn't seem possible to recover the list of IDs related to a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after some nights of struggle I've found a satisfying solution.

recursive function:

```
def getAllID(depth,ID):

if (depth==maxDepth):
    return

childs = getVideoRelated(depth,ID)

for x in range(0,len(childs)):
    videosId.append([childs[x][0], childs[x][1]])
    getAllID(childs[x][0]+1, childs[x][1])
```

instantiation of the recursive function with the first 'node' (aka video)

```
url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1hYcein2-Y'
initialID = f.get_id(url)

videosId.append([0,initialID])
getAllID(1,initialID)
```

It's still quite slow, but I can make it work:

If **maxDepth** = 5 and **numberOfRelated** = 5, I've got 32,1s 
If **maxDepth** = 6 and **numberOfRelated** = 5, I've got 156s

For what it worth, the global solution (with the data recovering from the ID graph) is  available here: https://github.com/kwnovi/melihat/blob/master/main.py